# How to delete elements of an array if the corresponding elements of another array have zero values in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the `HSI` array with a shape of (250, 1376, 176). It represents a hyperspectral image with 176 channels. I also have the ground truth image `GT` with a shape of (250, 1376). I want to delete the elements of the `GT` array that have zero values. So i used this:

```
GT_nonzero = GT[GT!= 0]
```

But then i have a vector. I would like to create a `GT_nonzero`  2D array. Is there a way that i can create a 2D array from a 2D array with the subtraction of the zero value elements?

Then, i want to delete the pixels of the `HSI` array (namely elements of the second and third axis of the array) that correspond to the elements of the `GT` array that have zero values.
I have tried with the `numpy.argwhere()` function to find the indices of the non-zero elements of the `GT` array but i am stucked and i can not find a solution.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: How are those 0 elements distributed?  What would be the shape of the desired 2d `GT_nonzero`?  Practice with a small `GT` so you get a clear(er) idea of what's happening.

Comment: why GT_nonzero = GT[GT!= 0] results in a 1d array (vector) ?

Comment: @pippo1980, indexing with a boolean array returns a 1d array; that's clearly stated in `numpy` indexing docs.

Comment: Imagine something like `x = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]`. What would you expect it to look like when you remove the zeros?

Comment: While you ponder that, I suggest looking into masked arrays.

Comment: @MadPhysicist too difficult right now, how is GT1[GT1!= 0] called ? need to check out this (got vector even for GT1 = np.random.randint(0,3,(4,4), 'uint8') that  shouldnt be a bollean array, or not ?), thanks for the hint I am trying to visualize arrays... kind of difficult

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html

Comment: @MadPhysicist mask=(GT1!= 0) GT_nonzero = GT[mask] , is it ?

Comment: @pippo1980. Yes. What shape would you wish it had, if it were up to you?

Comment: @MadPhysicist didn't know what GT_nonzero = GT[GT!= 0]  was, but the OP question sounded strange to me, why would you wamt to return a 1D vector loosing information from your data. Reading very fast on numpy.ma  (don't know how to do that yet) I would keep all the zeroes but marking them as invalid like: z = ma.masked_values([GT1], 0)

Answer (score 2):

First we need to clarify what do you want when you say you want to delete elements with value 0. In 1D-arrays it's easy, just drop that element, but in a 2D-array what do you do with that empty space? Maybe the rest of values of the same row and column are not zeros, so that element will still be occupying a space in that 2D-array. So I assume you want to delete full rows or columns where *all* of the elements are 0. That's the only way in which you could get rid of elements.

So to achieve that let's use a simple example, a 2D-array such as this one:

```python
GT = np.zeros((3,4))
GT[2,2] = 1
GT[2,0] = 1
GT[0,3] = 1
```

which has this form:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

so it's very visual that there's a row and a column with only 0s. Now what we can do is check what columns and rows only have 0s like this:

```python
#check if any row only has 0s
rows_to_delete = []
for i in range(np.shape(GT)[0]):
    if not np.any(GT[i]):
        rows_to_delete.append(i)

#check if any column only has 0s
columns_to_delete = []
for i in range(np.shape(GT)[1]):
    if not np.any(GT[:,i]):
        columns_to_delete.append(i)
```

So now that we have the appropriate rows and columns we just have to delete them, which we do using the `np.delete` method (the third parameter indicating the axis, 0 for rows and 1 for columns; and the second parameter indicating which specific row or column):

```python
GT_del = np.delete(np.delete(GT, rows_to_delete, 0), columns_to_delete, 1)
```

The above line deletes both rows and columns at once, but to see it in a clearer way you could separate it into two statements:

```python
GT_del_rows = np.delete(GT, rows_to_delete, 0)
GT_del_all = np.delete(GT_del_rows, columns_to_delete, 1)
```

So in this way you would have your GT 2D-array rid of empty rows and columns (final result shown below). From here I would suggest creating the HSI 2D-array from this one, since otherwise you should perform the same operation twice.

```
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0.]]
```